# how to subtract two columns output in a third column using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Using PHP I want to subtract each values of used column from credit column. I      have created a tableA in phpmyadmin.

remaining:credit-used  I can not get the results i just  get same values of credit.

```
// The desire output in table A

id |date      |credit |used|remaining|
1  |20-5-2013 |400    |300 |100      |
2  |19-5-2013 |300    |100 |200      |
3  |18-5-2013 |600    |50  |550      |  
// db connection  
query select all from tableA
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tableA";
    $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute           SQL query" '.$sql);
?>

fetch the information and output into a table:

<table >
<tr>
bla bla..
</tr>

// echo:

<tr>
<td><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["date"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["credit"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["used"]; ?></td>
```

I'm trying to do this query to get remaining:

```
// <td> <?php> echo $total= $row["credit"] - $row["used"];?> 
</td>  
</tr>
</table>
```

can anyone give me a hints or highlight the error. Than you very much in advance.

Comment: You are going to have to make an attempt to write some SQL before people are going to spoon feed you the answer.

Comment: I tried to do simple sql to get it. However when fetching data using php it gets complicated. I checked php tutorials not much information I found. With a simple example I can do it by myself. I tried the suggestions below but I got '0' I'm not sure if the query is wrong :mysql_query("SELECT *, 'credit'-'used' as 'remaining' FROM 'tablea'");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a closing bracket on your php

```
<td> <?php echo $row["credit"] - $row["used"]; ?> </td>
```

Comment: it is possible to substract two values using?  <?php echo $row["credit"] - $row["used"]; ?>

Comment: Yes, that will echo out the difference.

Comment: thank you for your answer. is there any way I can forward to you all my code because it doesn't work for me. I get 0 in the column i expect to get results

Answer (score 16):

What you have should work, but why not let MySQL do the calculation?

```
mysql_query("SELECT *, `credit`-`used` AS `remaining` FROM `tableA`");
```

Comment: <br /><br />
<table width="700" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
  <tr>    
    <td width="200" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>date</strong></td>
    <td width="350" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>credit</strong></td>
    <td width="100" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>used</strong></td>
 <td width="100" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Remaining</strong></td>
   </tr>

Comment: the column remaining gets ' 0'   echo:

Comment: <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["to_date"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["bundleselected"]; ?></td>
 <td> <?php echo $row["used"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row ["remaining"];?></td>
  </tr>

Comment: what to do when one of it sometime has null value then it is giving result null, for example `used=null` and `credit=123` then `credit-used` should be `123` but it is also returning null, what to do?

Comment: Don't make it nullable? `default 0` makes a lot more sense.